# react/redux fetching data from redux slice issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, redux-toolkit

I am creating a react/ redux app using json fake api server redux toolkit.
I am adding a some datas from and api to redux slice and trying to retrieve to my component. data seems empty and no error showing could anyone able to help me in this if possible.

my redux slice

---

```
import {
  createAsyncThunk,
  createSlice,
  createSelector,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
import { base_emp } from "./api";
const initialState = {
  emplist: [],
  loading: "loading",
};

export const fetchEmployees = createAsyncThunk(
  "employee/emplist",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(base_emp);
      return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ error: error.message });
    }
  }
);

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  // The `reducers` field lets us define reducers and generate associated actions
  reducers: {
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    // Use the PayloadAction type to declare the contents of `action.payload`
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchEmployees.pending, (state) => {
      state.emplist = [];
      state.loading = "loading";
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchEmployees.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.emplist = payload;
      state.loading = "loaded";
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchEmployees.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = "error";
      state.error = action.error.message;
    });
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = userSlice.actions;

export const selectCount = (state) => state.counter.value;

export const selectEmployees = createSelector(
  (state) => ({
    products: state.emplist,
    loading: state.loading,
  }),
  (state) => state
);

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

my component goes here

---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import EmployeeDetails from "./EmployeeDetails";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchEmployees, selectEmployees } from "./features/auth/userSlice";
const Employelist = () => {
  const [employe, setEmployee] = useState([]);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { emplist } = useSelector(selectEmployees);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchEmployees());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    emplist &&
      emplist.then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => setEmployee(data));
  }, []);
  const handleclick = (id) => {
    const emp = employe.filter((emp) => emp.employeeid !== id);
    setEmployee(emp);
  };
  // console.log(currentUsers);
  return (
    <div>
      <EmployeeDetails handleclick={handleclick} employe={employe} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Employelist;
```

api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export const base_emp = axios.get("http://localhost:5000/emp");
```

error message in console

---

[image]

Comment: There are a number of warnings in your console, and most seriously - your API request shows you are trying to stringify a promise itself rather than its result. I'd sort those out before asking about anything else! (The API 404 is presumably the reason for your app not working.) [EDIT: since you don't share your `api.js` I can't help you with what's wrong there, but it's probably something quite simple.]

Comment: @RobinZigmond updated Api.js  please check if possible tq

Comment: so `base_emp` is the promise, not its result. Assuming that the API response from `/emp` is itself a URL (which seems surprising but is possible), then you need another stage of promise-awaiting: `const url = await axios.get(base_emp); const response = await axios.get(url);`